# Changing on keyup to click event not triggering action

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add a click event on a function, but for some reason nothing is happening, no errors in the console and action is not triggered.
This is the plugin that I am altering: https://github.com/r-a-y/bbp-live-preview/blob/master/bbp-live-preview.php and on line 102 - 106

```
window.onload = function() {
    tinymce.get('bbp_<?php echo $type; ?>_content').on('keyup', function(e) {
        bbp_preview_post(this.getContent(), '<?php echo $type; ?>', true);
    });
}
```

this is the function that is triggering the event on `keyup`

I tried

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="bbp_topic_preview" class="button submit">Preview Topic</button>
```

Jquery - V1

```
window.onload = function() {
    tinymce.get('bbp_<?php echo $type; ?>_content').on('click', '#bbp_topic_preview', function(e) {
        bbp_preview_post(this.getContent(), '<?php echo $type; ?>', true);
    });
}
```

Jquery - V2

```
window.onload = function () {
    jQuery('#bbp_topic_preview').on('click', function() {
        tinymce.get('bbp_<?php echo $type; ?>_content').on('ready', function(e){
            bbp_preview_post( this.getContent(), '<?php echo $type; ?>', true );
        });
    });
}
```

But nothing is happening and no errors echoed in the console.

Comment: any one please, let me know how can I clarify further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. Needed to separate the function and assign the function  `tinymce.get..` into a variable which I passed it as argument to the function that contained object `this`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    jQuery('#bbp_topic_preview').on('click', function() {
        var get_contents = tinymce.get('bbp_<?php echo $type; ?>_content');
        bbp_preview_post( get_contents.getContent(), '<?php echo $type; ?>', true );
    });

}
```